# unicode error when calling windows terminal from RStudio but not R

Tags: r, windows, unicode, rstudio, whisper

I have an `.exe` that's meant to be called from the terminal/command line, and I want to use R to generate the program calls, iterate over different arguments, measure timings, capture output, and so forth.

The executable is [whisper-standalone-win](https://github.com/Purfview/whisper-standalone-win). From windows command line (`cmd.exe`), after `cd`'ing to the executable, we can do for example:

```
whisper-faster.exe --help
```

In R terminal (`R.exe`), we can do:

```
shell("whisper-faster.exe --help")
```

These both function as intended. However, in RStudio, I get:

```
#> [1] "Traceback (most recent call last):"                                                                                   
#> [2] "  File \"D:\\whisper-fast\\__main__.py\", line 666, in <module>"                                                      
#> [3] "  File \"D:\\whisper-fast\\__main__.py\", line 365, in cli"                                                           
#> [4] "  File \"argparse.py\", line 1768, in parse_args"                                                                     
#> [5] "  File \"argparse.py\", line 1800, in parse_known_args"                                                               
#> [6] "  File \"argparse.py\", line 2006, in _parse_known_args"                                                              
#> [7] "  File \"argparse.py\", line 1946, in consume_optional"                                                               
#> [8] "  File \"argparse.py\", line 1874, in take_action"                                                                    
#> [9] "  File \"argparse.py\", line 1044, in __call__"                                                                       
#> [10] "  File \"argparse.py\", line 2494, in print_help"                                                                     
#> [11] "  File \"argparse.py\", line 2500, in _print_message"                                                                 
#> [12] "  File \"encodings\\cp1252.py\", line 19, in encode"                                                                  
#> [13] "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\\u3002' in position 12754: character maps to <undefined>"
#> [14] "[23996] Failed to execute script '__main__' due to unhandled exception!"                                              
#> attr(,"status")
#> [1] 1
```

(I'm using `--help` as a simple example; this error also occurs with normal usage with an input audio file.) I've tried `system()` and `system2()` without luck. I'm aware of threads [here](https://github.com/openai/whisper/discussions/53) and [here](https://github.com/openai/whisper/discussions/729) about unicode errors with `whisper`, though it's not clear to me how to apply them to this usage.

I'm thinking of this as a sort of general problem of how to make sure I get the same results with `RStudio` as I do with `cmd` and `R` terminal. I'd really like to be able to do everything from the comfort of RStudio.

I'm on Windows 10 if that's important. I've tried `Sys.setenv(LANG = "en_US.UTF-8")` and a few other variations, also without success.

Comment: hmm I'd keep trying some unicode stuff like you have been doing. Then you could issue a bug with the whisper-standalone-win github. You could also try to just get the whisper as a python module and run that from R, see if that helps. Should at the very least allow you to fix the error